# Regression using ols on a non varying independent variable

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, regression, statsmodels

This is my dataset:

```
x   y   z

1   2   1
1   4   6
1   1   12
1   5   14
1   6   17
1   9   18
```

Now I want to do regression on this using the ols function of statsmodel library in python. For this I used:

> lm = smf.ols(formula='z ~ x + I(x+y)', data=data).fit()

Now I would be getting the coefficients of x, (x+y) and intercept. Since the independent variable x is constant through out the data set, its coefficient should be 0 as the dependent variable z does not depend on x value. But my output is different from expected. My output is:

```
Intercept         1.293173
col1              1.293173
I(col1 + col2)    1.590361
```

I used the same data to find the coefficients on R using the following function:

> m <- lm(z ~ x + I(x+y), data = new.data)

and for this my output is:

```
Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x     I(x + y)  
      2.586           NA        1.590
```

Why am I getting this error when I'm trying on ols model in python? How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: check the comment at the end of results.summary(), it should state that your model has eigenvalue that is close to zero. The problem is perfect colinearity which is handled differently in R and in statsmodels.

Comment: But the equation that I get from R and statsmodel are completely different which would give me error in my prediction. Could you explain in detail about the eigenvalues thing. Also, how can I overcome this problem? Is there a different package in python that i can use for prediction?

Comment: Your `x` variable is a constant with all ones. It "conflicts" with the intercept.  There are two solutions: do not consider the intercept in the model or do not use x in the model formula: `mod1 <- lm(z ~ 0 + x + I(x+y), data = new.data)` or `mod2 <- lm(z ~ I(x+y), data = new.data)`. The result is the same.